# Which way to run PostgreSQL in Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

Which of these methods is correct?

- One db container for each app
- One db container for all apps
- Install db without docker

I tried to find information, but nothing. Or I badly searched?

Comment: Personally I'd take option (3), without docker, at this point. The docker persistence stuff seems immature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is immature, but that doesn't seem to be stopping a lot of people using Docker for persistence.

The official [Postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) has 4.5 million pulls - Ok, this doesn't mean that all those images/containers are being used but it does suggest that it is a popular solution.

If you have already decided that you would like to use Docker, because of what containers can offer your architecture, then I don't think you will have trouble using it for persistence - assuming you are happy learning Docker.

I'm using Postgres and MySql in several projects quite successfully on Docker.

In choosing option 1 or 2, I would say that unless your apps are related to the same problem domain/company/project I would go with option 1. Of course, running costs will possibly factor in as well.

I generally go with option 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

All 3 options could be valid but it depends on the use you have to perform.

In my server I've 1 container for every main postgresql releases currently I use.

I run all of them on different ports (use not random number for ports but some easy to remember because a problem with docker is remember all port numbers and other for every container).

pg84(port 8432), pg93(port 9332), pg94 (port 9432)

I link the pgXX to the container I need and that's perfect for me.

For my experience I prefer option 2 so.